# Pending task in SonarQube & Stability config for Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-web

Our sonarqube server had 10+ pending tasks. I canceled one and now we can make tasks in the process.

How can I know they are pending now, and how to confirm when to cancel them? Because we want to manage sonar's tasks by Web API, not manually.

I find a `taskId` that I can use it to check the status of it. But how can I know the `taskId` without monitoring the console output of MAVEN BUILD?
taskId:`/api/ce/task?id=AVo_WHJYU5rNTJ7ZmiZq`

I tried to use this `api/ce/component` to get the status, but sometimes when I use `projectKey` as a component parameter, I got `"queue": []`. I can't get JSON `"current": {}`. Why it's empty because the `projectKey` is the correct one?

Another problem is how to configure the sonar.properties or etc? To make our sonar server, more stable (we only use one server, not cluster). Because I want to know why these tasks are pending.

My problems are:

1. I want to know how to check the status of a project task (`taskId`), then I can choose when and which one I need to cancel.
2. I want to know how to config my sonar better for best stability, just like JVM setting? My server's memory is 4 GB.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --location 'https://<SonarToken>@<Sonar-end-point>/api/ce/component?component=<Component-key>' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

This will fetch you the latest task id of background tasks

Take id from above response and pass it to task end point

```
curl --location 'https://<sonar-auth-token>@<Sonar-end-point>/api/ce/task?id=<Taskid>' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

**Sonar Version** : 9.9